# Jquery div each cycle gets all values in one row

Tags: jquery

I want jquery to cycle through some number of given div blocks, check if there is specific text in one of it, and do something if it returns true.

Here is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="months">
<div class="month-button">Jan</div>
<div class="month-button">Feb</div>
<div class="month-button">Mar</div>
<div class="month-button">Apr</div>
<div class="month-button">May</div>
<div class="month-button">Jun</div>
<div class="month-button">Jul</div>
<div class="month-button">Aug</div>
<div class="month-button">Sep</div>
<div class="month-button">Oct</div>
<div class="month-button">Nov</div>
<div class="month-button">Dec</div>
</div>
```

And here is my JS:

```
$('div.month-button').on('click', function(){
$('div.months div.month-button').each(function(){

    alert($('div.months div.month-button').text());

            if($('div.months div.month-button').text() == 'Apr')
            {
                alert($('div.months div.month-button').text());
            }

        });
    });
```

Problem is, this code above will return just one row with text from all div blocks. You can see this live here: http://jsfiddle.net/hmey6/
What's the way to force code return only one value from one div while it cycles through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `.click()` handler inside `.each()` as well as using `$(this)` to target current looped element:

```
$('div.months div.month-button').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        alert($(this).text());
        if ($(this).text() == 'Apr') {
            alert($(this).text());
        }
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmey6/1/)**

If you do not need to handle any additional task inside `.each()`, you can directly using:

```
$('div.months div.month-button').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).text());
    if ($(this).text() == 'Apr') {
        alert($(this).text());
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmey6/5/)**